# How to trace SOAP request from .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, trace

I have service reference to "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Soap.svc" in my C# project. I want to see what i send in my Http request with SOAP body to this service.

How i can it do?

Comment: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Thanks! I will try it!  But also interesting native C# solutions.

Comment: Native solution - write your own IDispatchMessageInspector, IClientMessageInspector, like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/04/23/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fiddler and other 3rd part dlls with your code to grab the soap messages and other details.

Answer (score 3):

If you use WCF to access the service you can enable message tracing (as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx)) to log SOAP envelops.